# como generar una fecha aleatoria entre dos rangos con random.randit en python

Tags: python

como generar una fecha aleatoria valida en python entre dos rangos  la función random.randit

```
def fechaRandom(x,y,z):
    assert fecha==int 
    return random.randint()
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que la manera más sencilla es usando `randint()` con los valores del [calendario gregoriano proléptico](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calendario_gregoriano_prol%C3%A9ptico) de las fechas, los cuales son accesibles a través del método `toordinal()` de los objetos de tipo `datetime`.

Luego, a partir del valor aleatorio obtenido, se puede reconstruir un nuevo objeto `datetime`, mediante la función `fromordinal()` de la clase `datetime`.

El código sería algo así.

```
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime


DATE_FORMAT = '%d/%m/%Y'


def get_random_date_between(date_a, date_b):    
    datetime_object_a = datetime.strptime(date_a, DATE_FORMAT)
    datetime_object_b = datetime.strptime(date_b, DATE_FORMAT)

    random_ordinal = randint(
        datetime_object_a.toordinal(),
        datetime_object_b.toordinal(),
    )

    random_date = datetime.fromordinal(random_ordinal)
    formatted_date_string = random_date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)

    return formatted_date_string
```

El cual puede ser usado de la siguiente manera:

```
>>> get_random_date_between('28/8/1993', '6/1/2021')
'30/10/2009'
>>> get_random_date_between('28/8/1993', '6/1/2021')
'21/11/1999'
```